# How can I do to read a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to read a file using jquery :

Here is my code :

```
var fileInput = $('#datafile');
readFile = function () {var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
console.log(reader.result);
};
// start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
};

fileInput.on('change', readFile);
```

But I got nothing in the console...

Could you help me please ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Accessing_selected_files_on_a_change_event

Comment: do all this staff on input `onchange` event. on load there is no file

Answer (score 1):

> But I got nothing in the console...

When I run that code (and change the value of the input) I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

`fileInput` is a *jQuery object*. It isn't a file input object. It doesn't have a `files` property (so `files` is `undefined` and it can't have a `0` property).

You need to deal with the input object:

```
fileInput[0].files[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

Local File Read and console Data

```js
$('#fileInput').on('change', function () {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      var data = fileReader.result;  //file data in Base64 format
      console.log(data);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL($('#fileInput').prop('files')[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">

</div>

<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```